# How to cope with tests coverage and impossible reached lines?

Tags: java, junit

I'm starting to work with Java and JUnit, and I'm facing some problem with understanding the tips and tricks about code coverage.

If I'm right, the ultimate goal in unit testing classes is to get to a 100% test coverage.

So here is the code that I have right now:

```
// field is of type Field (from reflection)

field.setAccessible(true);
try {
    field.get(instance);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So here, you can see that I can't access the catch() block at any time because I make the field Accessible just on top of it...

**What is wrong with my code? How can I get a 100% code coverage result when this happens?**

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but I would change the catch block to `throw new AssertionError();`.

Comment: 100% code coverage is a pipe-dream.  It is only achievable in trivial examples.

Comment: The target isn't 100%. You can't do it without really messing with your code. Instead, you do the best you can. As a significant portion of your code is error handling, some errors you can test for and some you can't. So you do your best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aim isn't to run 100% of your lines of code.  The aim is to test 100% of your system requirements, or rather 100% of the scenarios covered by your system requirements.

If you have code that doesn't play any part in fulfilling a system requirement, then you should consider deleting it.  In the example you've given, where code is required by the workings of the language, then you can leave it in; but don't worry at all about the fact that your reported code coverage drops below 100%.

Remember that code coverage percentage is only an approximation to the useful figure, which is the entirely unmeasurable "scenario coverage percentage".